# XSLT template match filter

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I'm able to use below XSLT to transform the XML which is returning expected output.

**XML**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <env:Body>
        <cc1:Get_Items_Response xmlns:cc1="urn:com.test/123" cc1:version="v1.0">
            
            <cc1:Response_Data>
                <cc1:Item>
                    <cc1:Item_Reference>
                        <cc1:ID cc1:type="Item_ID">12345</cc1:ID>
                    </cc1:Item_Reference>
                    <cc1:Item_Data>
                        <cc1:Item_ID>12345</cc1:Item_ID>                                                                    
                        
                        <cc1:Item_Classification_Data>
                            <cc1:Item_Classification_Reference>AAA</cc1:Item_Classification_Reference>
                            <cc1:Item_Classification_Field_Interface_Data>123</cc1:Item_Classification_Field_Interface_Data>
                        </cc1:Item_Classification_Data>
                        
                        <cc1:Item_Classification_Data>
                            <cc1:Item_Classification_Reference>BBB</cc1:Item_Classification_Reference>
                            <cc1:Item_Classification_Field_Interface_Data>456</cc1:Item_Classification_Field_Interface_Data>
                        </cc1:Item_Classification_Data>                                              
                        
                        
                    </cc1:Item_Data>
                </cc1:Item>
            </cc1:Response_Data>
        </cc1:Get_Items_Response>
    </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

**XSLT**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:cc1="urn:com.test/123" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">    
    
    <xsl:template match="cc1:Get_Items_Response/cc1:Response_Data/cc1:Item/cc1:Item_Data/cc1:Item_Classification_Data">
        <!-- Do nothing -->
    </xsl:template>    
    
    
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <env:Body>
        <cc1:Get_Items_Response xmlns:cc1="urn:com.test/123" cc1:version="v1.0">

            <cc1:Response_Data>
                <cc1:Item>
                    <cc1:Item_Reference>
                        <cc1:ID cc1:type="Item_ID">12345</cc1:ID>
                    </cc1:Item_Reference>
                    <cc1:Item_Data>
                        <cc1:Item_ID>12345</cc1:Item_ID>
                    </cc1:Item_Data>
                </cc1:Item>
            </cc1:Response_Data>
        </cc1:Get_Items_Response>
    </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

Question: I'm trying to transform the xml into desired xml using xslt. Can anyone help with xslt transformation. If I wanted to get the output as below, how should I modify the XSLT ?

Question: I'm trying to transform the xml into desired xml using xslt. Can anyone help with xslt transformation. If I wanted to get the output as below, how should I modify the XSLT ?

Question: I'm trying to transform the xml into desired xml using xslt. Can anyone help with xslt transformation. If I wanted to get the output as below, how should I modify the XSLT ?

Question: I'm trying to transform the xml into desired xml using xslt. Can anyone help with xslt transformation. If I wanted to get the output as below, how should I modify the XSLT ?

**Desired Output**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <env:Body>
        <cc1:Get_Items_Response xmlns:cc1="urn:com.test/123" cc1:version="v1.0">
            
            <cc1:Response_Data>
                <cc1:Item>
                    <cc1:Item_Reference>
                        <cc1:ID cc1:type="Item_ID">12345</cc1:ID>
                    </cc1:Item_Reference>
                    <cc1:Item_Data>
                        <cc1:Item_ID>12345</cc1:Item_ID>                                                                    
                        
                        <cc1:Item_Classification_Data>
                            <cc1:Item_Classification_Reference>AAA</cc1:Item_Classification_Reference>
                            <cc1:Item_Classification_Field_Interface_Data>123</cc1:Item_Classification_Field_Interface_Data>
                        </cc1:Item_Classification_Data>                                                                                             
                        
                    </cc1:Item_Data>
                </cc1:Item>
            </cc1:Response_Data>
        </cc1:Get_Items_Response>
    </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

Comment: On what do you want to filter?
1. On content: AAA or BBB
2. On position: first or second cc1:Item_Classification_Data

Comment: I want to filter complete `cc1:Item_Classification_Data` node where cc1:Item_Classification_Reference = BBB

Comment: Then use the first answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67000538/3710053 I suppose

Comment: It didn't work with below changes.                                                             
 ```<xsl:template match="cc1:Get_Items_Response/cc1:Response_Data/cc1:Item/cc1:Item_Data/cc1:Item_Classification_Data[text()='BBB']">
    <!-- Do nothing -->
</xsl:template>```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then use this:

```
<xsl:template match="cc1:Item_Classification_Data[cc1:Item_Classification_Reference[text()='BBB']]">
    <!-- Do nothing -->
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thank you. Perfect

Answer (score 0):

Try writing your template line like this.

```
<xsl:template match="cc1:Get_Items_Response/cc1:Response_Data/cc1:Item/cc1:Item_Data/cc1:Item_Classification_Data[text()='BBB']">
    <!-- Do nothing -->
</xsl:template>
```